# Is there a list of Symfony2 default container services?

Tags: symfony, dependency-injection

Here is an example, taken from Symfony2 website, about **defining a custom service** (YAML notation):

```
services:
    newsletter_manager:
        class:     %newsletter_manager.class%
        arguments: [@mailer, @templating]
```

Is there a **list of default Symfony2 service objects** that can be injected into a custom service as parameters (like `@mailer`, `@templating`, `@doctrine`)?

I know that they come from the `Container` (which is available, for example, in each `Controller` class). I've tryed to dump all services, but i'm looking for a more detailed list:

```
php app/console container:debug

logger container Symfony\Bridge\Monolog\Logger
mailer container Swift_Mailer
translator n/a alias for translator.default
...
```

Comment: define 'a more detailed list'.

Comment: I'm sure I saw a list of all the standard edition services that come 'out of the box' on the symfony.com website in the reference area. But I can't find it now.

Comment: `php app/console container:debug` will give you a list of all the registered services

Answer (score 121, accepted):

The command line `php app/console container:debug` shows the list of services you can inject into another service or get from a `Controller with Controller::get($serviceName)`.

This list shows only **public** services. Add the option `--show-private` into display **private** services. Private services can only be injected in another service, not accessed from a Controller or any ContainerAware...

**EDIT**: From Symfony 2.7, use `debug:container` instead of `container:debug`

Comment: The use of "container:debug" command is deprecated since version 2.7 and will be removed in 3.0. Use the "debug:container" instead.

=> https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/c8475c938d55eb8e7c7df53177b346012b39159c/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Command/ContainerDebugCommand.php#L99

Comment: The console moved to `bin/console` in Symfony 3.

Answer (score 5):

you can also do this if you want to get details of a single service:

```
    php app/console container:debug service_id
```

this will give you info on that service

Comment: Run `php app/console container:debug` in order to list the services.

Answer (score 4):

The [WebProfilerExtraBundle](https://github.com/Elao/WebProfilerExtraBundle) is very useful for this.

It also adds some details about routing, assetic and twig that are very helpful. As a someone learning to think in Symfony, I REALLY like this bundle.

Answer (score 3):

you can use

```
    php app/console container:debug
```

to get a list of all available public service IDs
or

```
    php app/console container:debug --show-private
```

to show both public and private service IDs

Answer (score 3):

you can use following command to get desired service details:

```
php app/console container:debug | grep service_name
```

Answer (score 2):

You can list services with

```
php app/console debug:container log
```

If you need more about some service you can use the help

```
php app/console debug:container log  --help
```