# Where does symfony2 store the default services it has?

Tags: symfony

Symfony has some default services like

```
 $this->get("session")
```

and so on..
Where are the services defined ?

Comment: does it answer your question => http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9473846/is-there-a-list-of-symfony2-default-container-services

Answer (score 0):

This service is defined here in Symfony2:

```
Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Session;
```

and run this command and see symfony2 all services:

```
  php app/console container:debug
```